# Convert "1d2h3m" to ["day" => 1, ”hour” => 2,"minutes"=>3]

Tags: php, arrays, time, associative-array, text-parsing

I am trying to parse a time expression string into an associative array with full-word keys.

My input:

```
$time = "1d2h3m";
```

My desired output:

```
array(
    "day" => 1,
    "hour" => 2,
    "minutes" => 3
)
```

I have tried to extract the numbers with `explode()`.

```
$time = "1d2h3m";
$day = explode("d", $time);
var_dump($day); // 0 => string '1' (length=1)
                // 1 => string '2h3m' (length=4)
```

How can I convert my strictly formatted string into the desired associative array?

Comment: Where is the $ol defined?

Comment: explode the resulting array twice, each with `h` and `m`, do it inside a loop and array_push into another array.

Answer (score 25):

A simple [`sscanf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php) will parse this into an array. Then you [`array_combine`](http://php.net/array_combine) it with the list of keys you want.

#### Example:

```
$time = "1d2h3m";

$result = array_combine(
    ['day', 'hour', 'minutes'],
    sscanf($time, '%dd%dh%dm')
);

print_r($result);
```

#### Output:

```
Array
(
    [day] => 1
    [hour] => 2
    [minutes] => 3
)
```

---

To break down the `sscanf` format used:

- `%d` - reads a (signed) decimal number, outputs an integer
- `d` - matches the literal character "d"
- `%d` - (as the first)
- `h` - matches the literal character "h"
- `%d` - (as the first)
- `m` - matches the literal character "m" (optional, as it comes after everything you want to grab)

---

It'll also work fine with multiple digits and negative values:

```
$time = "42d-5h3m";
Array
(
    [day] => 42
    [hour] => -5
    [minutes] => 3
)
```

Answer (score 16):

You should go with regex for this case

```
<?php
 $time = "1d2h3m";
 if(preg_match("/([0-9]+)d([0-9]+)h([0-9]+)m/i",$time,$regx_time)){
    $day = (int) $regx_time[1];
    $hour = (int) $regx_time[2];
    $minute = (int) $regx_time[3];
    var_dump($day);
 }
?>
```

Explaination :
**[0-9]** : Match any digits between 0 and 9
**[0-9]+** : Means, match digits at least one character
**([0-9]+)** : Means, match digits at least one character and capture the results
**/........../i** : Set the case insenstive for the pattern of regex you've setted

Regex is the way better to be a lexer and parse string lexically. And it's good to learn regex. Almost all programming language use regex

Comment: Just compare this basic RegEx with the rest.  I have no idea why college/university don't teach RegEx.

Answer (score 13):

Customizable function, and the most important thing, that you can catch an exception if input is not properly formed

```
/**
  * @param $inputs string : date time on this format 1d2h3m
  * @return array on this format                 "day"      => 1,
  *                                              "hour"     => 2,
  *                                              "minutes"  => 3        
  * @throws Exception
  *
  */
function dateTimeConverter($inputs) {
    // here you can customize how the function interprets input data and how it should return the result
    // example : you can add "y"    => "year"
    //                       "s"    => "seconds"
    //                       "u"    => "microsecond"
    // key, can be also a string
    // example                "us"  => "microsecond"
    $dateTimeIndex  = array("d" => "day",
                               "h" => "hour",
                               "m" => "minutes");

    $pattern        = "#(([0-9]+)([a-z]+))#";
    $r              = preg_match_all($pattern, $inputs, $matches);
    if ($r === FALSE) {
        throw new Exception("can not parse input data");
    }
    if (count($matches) != 4) {
        throw new Exception("something wrong with input data");
    }
    $datei      = $matches[2]; // contains number
    $dates      = $matches[3]; // contains char or string
    $result    = array();
    for ($i=0 ; $i<count ($dates) ; $i++) {
        if(!array_key_exists($dates[$i], $dateTimeIndex)) {
            throw new Exception ("dateTimeIndex is not configured properly, please add this index : [" . $dates[$i] . "]");
        }
        $result[$dateTimeIndex[$dates[$i]]] = (int)$datei[$i];
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: @Sorin in this case you should adapt **$dateTimeIndex** in this way to avoid ambiguity `$dateTimeIndex  = array( "mon" => "month",
                                                                        "d"      => "day",
                                                                        "h"      => "hour",
                                                                        "min"  => "minutes");`
And, for sure, the input string must obey the rule :)

Comment: There is no benefit in wrapping the whole pattern in capturing parentheses.  This is unnecessarily bloating the matches array.

Answer (score 5):

Another regex solution

```
$subject = '1d2h3m';
if(preg_match('/(?P<day>\d+)d(?P<hour>\d+)h(?P<minute>\d+)m/',$subject,$matches))
{
  $result = array_map('intval',array_intersect_key($matches,array_flip(array_filter(array_keys($matches),'is_string'))));
  var_dump($result);
}
```

Returns

```
array (size=3)
  'day' => int 1
  'hour' => int 2
  'minute' => int 3
```

Comment: Sorry, I post a comment by mistake. It was mean for another (not your) post.

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.  I don't think I recommend this answer, since this task can be accomplished in just one native function call versus ...I don't know how many -- I lost count, is it 10 function calls?

Answer (score 5):

Use this simple implementation with string replace and array combine.

```
<?php
   $time = "1d2h3m";
   $time=str_replace(array("d","h","m")," " ,$time);
   $time=array_combine(array("day","hour","minute"),explode(" ",$time,3));

   print_r($time);
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think for such a small string, and if the format will always be the same, you could use `array_push` and `substr` to get extract the numbers out of the string and put them in an array.

```
<?php
$time = "1d2h3m";
$array = array();
array_push($array, (int) substr($time, 0, 1));
array_push($array, (int) substr($time, 2, 1));
array_push($array, (int) substr($time, 4, 1));
var_dump($array);
?>
```

Comment: I don't think it is a very attractive solution to use 6 function calls when one function call can do this job.

Answer (score 4):

This approach uses a regular expression to extract the values and an array to map the letters to the words.

```
<?php
   // Initialize target array as empty
   $values = [];

   // Use $units to map the letters to the words
   $units = ['d'=>'days','h'=>'hours','m'=>'minutes'];

   // Test value
   $time = '1d2h3m';

   // Extract out all the digits and letters
   $data = preg_match_all('/(\d+)([dhm])/',$time,$matches);

   // The second (index 1) array has the values (digits)
   $unitValues = $matches[1];

   // The third (index 2) array has the keys (letters)
   $unitKeys = $matches[2];

   // Loop through all the values and use the key as an index into the keys
   foreach ($unitValues as $k => $v) {
       $values[$units[$unitKeys[$k]]] = $v;
   }
```

Comment: array_combine(array_values(array_intersect_key($units,array_fill_keys($matches[2],1))),$matches[1])) ?

Comment: @Sorin - That's a nice solution.  The reason I used the **foreach** is that it is only three elements and I like the simplicity of the loop.

Comment: I understand, I was mostly joking, I started writing it thinking it would be cleaner, but by the end it was clear it's harder to follow ;) foreach is fine php isn't really a functional language

Answer (score 3):

`preg_split` returns an array of values split by pattern(`#[dhm]#`).

`list()` sets the value for each array element.

```
$d = [];
list($d['day'],$d['hour'],$d['minutes']) = preg_split('#[dhm]#',"1d2h3m");
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just explode it 3 times...

```
// Define an array
$day = explode("d", $time);
// add it in array with key as "day" and first element as value
$hour= explode("h", <use second value from above explode>);
// add it in array with key as "hour" and first element as value
$minute= explode("m", <use second value from above explode>);
// add it in array with key as "minute" and first element as value
```

I don't have any working example right now but I think it will work.

Comment: I don't think I recommend this 4th-of-July technique.  This task can be resolved with a single function call.

Answer (score 0):

We can **also** achieve this using [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function.

```
$time = "1d2h3m"; 
$time = str_replace(array("d","h","m"), "*", $time);
$exp_time =  explode("*", $time); 
$my_array =  array(  "day"=>(int)$exp_time[0],
                     "hour"=>(int)$exp_time[1],
                     "minutes"=>(int)$exp_time[2] ); 
var_dump($my_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$time = "1d2h3m";
$split = preg_split("/[dhm]/",$time);
$day = array(
    "day"     => $split[0]
    "hour"    => $split[1]
    "minutes" => $split[2]
);
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use one line solution,

```
$time = "1d2h3m";
$day = array_combine(
           array("day","hour","months")   , 
           preg_split("/[dhm]/", substr($time,0,-1)  )    
       );
```

Comment: Why do you split on `m` if you unconditionally remove `m` from the string before you split it?  This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of great answers here, but I want to add one more, to show a more generic approach.

```
function parseUnits($input, $units = array('d'=>'days','h'=>'hours','m' => 'minutes')) {
    $offset = 0;
    $idx = 0;

    $result = array();
    while(preg_match('/(\d+)(\D+)/', $input,$match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $offset)) {
        $offset = $match[2][1];

        //ignore spaces
        $unit = trim($match[2][0]);
        if (array_key_exists($unit,$units)) { 
            // Check if the unit was allready found
            if (isset($result[$units[$unit]])) {  
                throw new Exception("duplicate unit $unit");
            }

            // Check for corect order of units
            $new_idx = array_search($unit,array_keys($units));
            if ($new_idx < $idx) {
                throw new Exception("unit $unit out of order");             
            } else {
                $idx = $new_idx;
            }
            $result[$units[trim($match[2][0])]] = $match[1][0];

        } else {
            throw new Exception("unknown unit $unit");
        }
    }
    // add missing units
    foreach (array_keys(array_diff_key(array_flip($units),$result)) as $key) {
        $result[$key] = 0;
    }
    return $result;
}
print_r(parseUnits('1d3m'));
print_r(parseUnits('8h9m'));
print_r(parseUnits('2d8h'));
print_r(parseUnits("3'4\"", array("'" => 'feet', '"' => 'inches')));
print_r(parseUnits("3'", array("'" => 'feet', '"' => 'inches')));
print_r(parseUnits("3m 5 d 5h 1M 10s", array('y' => 'years', 
           'm' => 'months', 'd' =>'days', 'h' => 'hours', 
           'M' => 'minutes', "'" => 'minutes', 's' => 'seconds' )));
print_r(parseUnits("3m 5 d 5h 1' 10s", array('y' => 'years', 
           'm' => 'months', 'd' =>'days', 'h' => 'hours',
           'M' => 'minutes', "'" => 'minutes', 's' => 'seconds' )));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this fn to get the formatted array which check for the string validation as well :

```
function getFormatTm($str)
{
    $tm=preg_split("/[a-zA-z]/", $str);

    if(count($tm)!=4) //if not a valid string
       return "not valid string<br>";
    else
       return array("day"=>$tm[0],"hour"=>$tm[1],"minutes"=>$tm[2]);
}
$t=getFormatTm("1d2h3m");
var_dump($t);
```

Answer (score 0):

*This answer is not 100% relevant to particular input string format from the question.*

But it based on the **PHP date parsing mechanism** (is not my own date parsing bicycle).

> PHP >=5.3.0 has `DateInterval` class.

You could create DateInterval objects from stings in two formats:

```
$i = new DateInterval('P1DT12H'); // ISO8601 format
$i = createFromDateString('1 day + 12 hours'); // human format
```

PHP official docs: http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.createfromdatestring.php

In ISO8601 format `P` stands for "period". Format supports three forms of the periods:

- PnYnMnDTnHnMnS
- PnW
- PT

Capital letters represents the following:

- P is the duration designator (historically called "period") placed at the start of the duration representation.
- Y is the year designator that follows the value for the number of years.
- M is the month designator that follows the value for the number of months.
- W is the week designator that follows the value for the number of
  weeks.
- D is the day designator that follows the value for the number of
  days.
- T is the time designator that precedes the time components of the
  representation.
- H is the hour designator that follows the value for the number of
  hours.
- M is the minute designator that follows the value for the number of
  minutes.
- S is the second designator that follows the value for the number of
  seconds.

> For example, "**P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S**" represents a duration of "**three years,
>   six months, four days, twelve hours, thirty minutes, and five
>   seconds**".

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations for details.

Answer (score 0):

One line code:

```
$result = array_combine(array("day", "hour", "minutes"), preg_split('/[dhm]/', "1d2h3m", -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Answer (score 0):

`sscanf()` is certainly an ideal tool for this job.  Unlike `preg_match()`, this native text parsing function avoids creating a useless fullstring match.  The numeric values that are extracted can be cast as integers and directly assigned to their respective keys in the result array.

Code (creates reference variables): ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/KZJDJ))

```
$time = "1d2h3m";
sscanf($time, '%dd%dh%dm', $result['day'], $result['hour'], $result['minutes']);
var_export($result);
```

or if you are processing multiple strings in a loop and want to avoid creating reference variables (or find it ugly to `unset()` the variables at the end of each iteration), then you can "destructure" the return array into the desired associative structure.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/rkNt8))

```
$time = "1d2h3m";
[$result['day'], $result['hour'], $result['minutes']] = sscanf($time, '%dd%dh%dm');
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'day' => 1,
  'hour' => 2,
  'minutes' => 3,
)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do using this code.

```
<?php
$str = "1d2h3m";
list($arr['day'],$arr['day'],$arr['hour'],$arr['hour'],$arr['minute'],$arr['minute']) = $str;
print_r($arr);
?>
```

> OUTPUT

```
Array ( 
   [minute] => 3
   [hour] => 2
   [day] => 1
)
```

[**DEMO**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/592x-2s3a)

Comment: You solution does not work with two-digits numbers of days, hours and minutes.